# Why can't I import the image as a prop in React?

Tags: reactjs, image

I want to import an img as a prop with react, but it does not work. I fear that the problem has
something to do with the compiler, but I do not know. I have tried the following things:

This is the img/path data I want to import:

```
export default [
    {
        title: "Learning ",
        imgPath: "react-logo.png",
        description: "test test test test test test leonard one two three four"

    }
]
```

This is the app component that recieves this data and sends it to the Main component:

```
import './App.css'
import Navbar from './components/navbar'
import Main from './components/main'
import data from './components/data'


function App() {

const infoCards = data.map((item) => {
  return (
    <Main
    {...item}
    />
  )
})


  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      {infoCards}
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

And I want to display this through the main component:

```
import image from "../assets/react-logo.png"

const Main = (props) => {
    return (
        <main className="flex flex-col w-full px-[20%] border-4">
            <div className="card border-[2px] border-black flex rounded-lg">
                <img src={image} alt="" className="w-32" />
                <div className="cardInfo text-center">
                    <h1>{props.title}</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, non?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
     );
}
 
export default Main;
```

I tried using require but I does not work

```
const Main = (props) => {
    return (
        <main className="flex flex-col w-full px-[20%] border-4">
            <div className="card border-[2px] border-black flex rounded-lg">
                <img src={require("../assets/react-logo.png")} alt="" className="w-32" />
                <div className="cardInfo text-center">
                    <h1>{props.title}</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, non?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
     );
}
 
export default Main;
```

I did also try using normal props-passing, but same story here:

```
const Main = (props) => {
    return (
        <main className="flex flex-col w-full px-[20%] border-4">
            <div className="card border-[2px] border-black flex rounded-lg">
                <img src={props.imgPath} alt="" className="w-32" />
                <div className="cardInfo text-center">
                    <h1>{props.title}</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, non?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
     );
}
 
export default Main;
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).